# animate uibutton applying images swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I want to apply animation effect by changing two images on button turn by turn. I have applied following code but not able to see animation effect.
I have applied IBOutlets properly.

```
    var image1:UIImage = UIImage(named: "img_mic_off")!
    var image2:UIImage = UIImage(named: "img_mic_on")!
    btnRecord.imageView?.animationImages = [image1,image1]
    btnRecord.imageView?.animationDuration = 1.0
    btnRecord.imageView!.startAnimating()
```

Please help me to resolve issue that why it is not working with this given code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to animate from `image1` to `image1` ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's nothing wrong with your current code other than your array is rotating through just one image. Change your third line to include image2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out what I've done. The images are changing. So I hope this is what you actually needed.

```
var image1:UIImage = UIImage(named: "img_mic_off")!
var image2:UIImage = UIImage(named: "img_mic_on")!
btn.setImage(image1, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btn.imageView!.animationImages = [image1, image2]
btn.imageView!.animationDuration = 1.0
btn.imageView!.startAnimating()
```

Comment: Can you add a completion handler to this?

Answer (score 1):

The animation property simply cycles through the image array and changes them at interval of durationInSeconds/numberOfImagesInArray.

So, to have a smooth image animation you will need to have a set of intermediate transition images.

Higher the number of images in set, smoother the animation.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

Don't forget to unwrap!

```
        if let image1 = UIImage(named: "img_mic_off"), let image2 = UIImage(named: "img_mic_on") {
        btn.setImage(image1, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        btn.imageView?.animationImages = [image1, image2]
        btn.imageView?.animationDuration = 1.0
        btn.imageView?.startAnimating()
    }
```