# Is it possible to make 'UIControlState.Highlighted' fade out for a button?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

Ive got this line of code that changes the image on a button when clicked:

```
sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "something.png")!, forState: .Highlighted)
```

I want the button to fade back in to the original image.

Is this possible?

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30122653/4687211 ?

Comment: @monchote Thank you! Exactly what I wanted